# Is there a way to make Tkinter Labels and Buttons the same size by default?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

Main = Tk()

Frame_Top = Frame(Main, bg='red')
Label_Left = Label(Frame_Top, width=8, height=1, relief=SUNKEN, text='label')
Button_Right = Button(Frame_Top, width=8, height=1, relief=RAISED, text='button')

Frame_Top.pack()
Label_Left.pack(side='left')
Button_Right.pack(side='left')

Main.mainloop()
```

When I run this, the label is smaller than the button. Rather than using `fill='y'` or `sticky='ns'`, is there a way I can make the Label and Button the same size / width, height ratio by default?

Comment: You can't change the "default" behavior, but you can certainly configure the widgets to be a certain size.

Comment: You can also override the propagation with something like `pack_propagate(0)`